# Delay Activity not firing in SharePoint Workflow

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I have a delay activity with an interval set to 1 day.
For some reason the workflow Timer is not activating the workflow once the time has elapsed.

I have installed the SharePoint infrastructure update, but it did not resolve the issue.

The workflow is also set to listen for an item change event, if I change the item after the delay interval the delay is activated.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

I had this experience as well, and got confused about what the problem is.  For me, it turned out to be this, which has a hotfix:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;932394

I don't think this would have been included in the SharePoint infrastructure update, as this is a problem with the .NET Framework and Windows Workflow Foundation rather than SharePoint specifically.